# Does the Pinterest validator work?

Tags: validation, schema.org, pinterest, pins

I'm trying to embed rich pins to our website. I used Schema.org for Product. While Google validates [correctly the page](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fsealsmile.com%2Fproducts%2Fsearch%3Fkeyphrase%3Dsmart%26category%3D%26resultType%3Dproduct), when I m trying the Pinterest validator I'm always getting the following error:

> The data we scraped from your site could not be validated. Please make sure all required tags are present and you aren't serving different pages depending on different user agents.
>
> [image]

Anybody had the same experience and somehow managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was quite simply to use "http://www.example.com" instead of "http://example.com"

That was it. Didn't need to change anything else.

So I notice you're also using:

```
https://sealsmile.com/products/search?keyphrase=smart&category=&resultType=product
```

try using:

```
https://www.sealsmile.com/products/search?keyphrase=smart&category=&resultType=product
```